# Dynamic React Native Icon

Tags: react-native

I am using `react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome`

Following code is working :

`<Icon name='{this.state.icon}' size={40} style={{paddingRight:20,color: '#61D379'}}/>`

Whereas I want icon name from API, It has to be dynamic.
I console log `this.state.icon` is says `check-circle`

But when I put

`<Icon name='{this.state.icon}' size={40} style={{paddingRight:20,color: '#61D379'}}/>`

Undefined Icon comes up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove quotes from name.I hope it will helps you.

```
<Icon name={this.state.icon} size={40} style={{paddingRight:20,color: '#61D379'}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not correctly sending name here

```
<Icon name='{this.state.icon}' size={40} style={{paddingRight:20,color: '#61D379'}}/>
```

Change this to

```
<Icon name={this.state.icon} size={40} style={{paddingRight:20,color: '#61D379'}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if the icon exist before you use it. The reason is since you are fetching the name from an api, the first render might run and during that period the `this.state.icon` is not yet available and undefined as such you receive the error

```
<Icon name={this.state.icon ? this.state.icon : "defult-icon-name-here"} size={40} style={{paddingRight:20,color: '#61D379'}}/>
```